# Convert array of string in array on long with closure

Tags: groovy

I have this string:

```
String t="123;123;123"
```

And I want to convert it in a list of Long, what I did so far is this:

```
t.split(";")
```

Which gives me back an array of String, now I'd like to convert it in an array of Long. I'd like to know if there is a way to do it with clousure instead of looping the array and move every single converted element in a new array.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Collection#collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)).

```
t.split(";").collect { it.toLong() }
```

Does what you want.

Try it: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5172355898802176

Answer (score 1):

Same effect as Mene's answer can be accomplished even shorter with the [groovy spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator):

```
t.split(';')*.toLong()
```